# Synchronize internal and external Confluence space

Tags: confluence

I would like to synchronize two Confluence spaces that exist in two different environments. The logic behind is the following:

We want to have an internal draft space that the client can't see and an external space (client space) where can push our validated content to.

Is such thing possible with Confluence plug-ins?

I already found the Comala publishing plug-in but I don't think it supports spaces that are located in an external environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine [Comala Workflows](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.comalatech.workflow/server/overview) (paid add-on) with [Comala Workflows - Remote Publishing](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.comalatech.remotepublishing/server/overview) (free add-on that requires Comala Workflows) for doing so. In draft space (source Confluence instance) you set up a simple workflow, which publishes the approved pages to the external space (target client instance).

Give it a try and drop us a line in case you have troubles ([support](https://comalatech.zendesk.com/)).

**Disclaimer**: I work in Comalatech, the company behind those add-ons.

Regards,
Gorka